# C# NetworkCredential in PHP

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, networkcredentials

I am trying to access a webservice through PHP. The webservice returns a byte array with a jpeg image, which is then shown on a webpage.

Today the service is accesses by a C# call, like so

```
ImgService i = new ImgService();
```

The credentials are set like this:

```
i.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
```

Access to webservice:

```
byte[] result = null;

result = i.GetThumbNail(raceId, startNum, seasonId, height, width, true);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.BinaryWrite(result);
```

The service is working fine in C# but now I need to access it through PHP and the only image I am getting is "missing.jpg". I am not sure if this means that the credentials are wrong or if something else is wrong, but I feel very unsure about the credentials part.

This is the PHP code without any credentials:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.example.com/imgService.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client->GetThumbNail($args['race'], $args['startnumber'], $args['year'], 0, 0, true);
$image_data = $result->GetThumbNailResult;
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image_data).'">';
```

I have also tried using calls like this:

```
$headers = array(
                            'username'  =>  'user',
                            'password'  =>  'pass',
                            'domain'    =>  'domain'
                            );
$header = new SoapHeader("http://tempuri.org/", 'UserCredentials', $headers, false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$result = $client->GetThumbNail(parameters);
```

Both versions gives me the same missing.jpg and no error message. I feel I would get an error if the service did not accept the call?

Comment: Did you try using some tool to compare the web-requests? E.g. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: @ChrFin I actually just tried it in Fiddler and a call to the C# file show_thumbnail.aspx (which makes the call to the service) with correct data presents me with the wanted image.
Edit: Realised that then the credentials are valid since the call is made from C#. Not sure how I call the SOAP service in Fiddler?

Comment: Make the call once with C# and once with PHP and then compare the actual requests sent over the wire...

Comment: @ChrFin oh you mean make the call from localhost and analyze the requests? I'll see if I can fix that. Calls are made from different servers atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not manage to solve this problem with the old web service, so I ended up creating a new HttpHandler doing the same thing the old service did.
Oh well...